# Why my foreach breaks when I try to draw dynamic buttons in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to draw dynamic buttons inside a foreach loop that retrieve data from my anko sqlite, the foreach only enter once and breaks and only draw one button in my layout, what I doing wrong? my code is this:

```
fun loadZones (ctx: Context, update: String, view: View, layout: LinearLayout) {
    val zonesParser = rowParser{idzone: Int, zone: String -> Pair(idzone, zone)}
    for (it in ctx.database.use {
        select("tableplan")
            .distinct()
            .column("idzone")
            .column("zone")
            .orderBy("zone")
            .parseList(zonesParser)
    }) {
        val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val btnZone = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.zones_item, null) as MaterialButton
        btnZone.text = it.second
        btnZone.id = it.first
        layout.addView(btnZone, layoutParams)
        Log.e("PAIR", "FIN DEL CICLO")
        continue
    }
}
```

The data that retrieves from my query is this:

```
(2, LARRY)
(1, MADISON)
```

That's my activity, I need to draw the buttons in **"lytZonesButtons"** id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".TablePlanFragment">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:elevation="2dp"
                                                     tools:targetApi="lollipop" app:liftOnScroll="true">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTablePlan"
                style="@style/com.madison.Toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="@string/table_title_module">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/orangeLighter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/lytZonesButtons" />
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:padding="5dp">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rc_tableplan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and that's my button template that I called "zones_item":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" style="@style/com.madison.AppButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2"
        tools:text="MADISON"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
/>
```

**EDIT**: I found the solution!

I don't now why my layout instance in the twice iteration of my loop throws `NullPointerException` but not shows in the log cat, my solution was put the loop code in onCreateView function, this is the code:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tableplan, container, false)
        val iActivity = (activity as AppCompatActivity)
        iActivity.setSupportActionBar(view.toolbarTablePlan)
        iActivity.supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
        // view.rc_tableplan.setHasFixedSize(true)
        // val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        // view.rc_tableplan.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        val response = loadTablePlan(this.context!!, "no")
        if (response.trim().toUpperCase() == "SUCCESS") {
            val zonesParser = rowParser{idzone: Int, zone: String -> Pair(idzone, zone)}
            for (zone in this.context!!.database.use {
                select("tableplan")
                    .distinct()
                    .column("idzone")
                    .column("zone")
                    .orderBy("zone")
                    .parseList(zonesParser)
            }) {
                val layout:LinearLayout = view.lytZonesButtons
                layout.let {
                    val btnZone = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.zones_item, layout, false) as MaterialButton
                    btnZone.text = zone.second
                    btnZone.id = zone.first
                    btnZone.requestLayout()
                    layout.addView(btnZone)
                    Log.e("PAIR", "FIN DEL CICLO")
                }
            }
        }
        return view
    }
```

Thanks a lot for all people that tried help me, some admin can close my question please.

Comment: I don't know why the "continue" keyword is there. Can you remove it and try again?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the data retrieved from query to a variable and check its length right before the for-loop?

Comment: @Crummy yes, I put "continue" after trying, I thought that maybe with "continue" it was going to be fixed, but it's still the same.

Comment: @Ricky Mo, yes I print the retrieved data, and shows me two records, if I quit the MaterialButton instance the loop throws me the two records.

Comment: What if you change the for loop to be `for (it in listOf(Pair(2, "LARRY"), Pair(1, "MADISON")))` ?

Comment: @Crummy I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The hint is only one button is showing. Your trying to inflate the same view twice in the same spot.

You need to add an empty linearlayout in your xml. And in your loop change the buttonz..

```
var btnZone = findViewById(R.layout.btnZone) 
button.text = "Pair"
btnZone.addView(button, layoutParams)
```

That's not the exact code (and probably not even the right syntax) but it shows you how you need to modify your loop.

Basicly you were attempting to inflate the same instance of the same view. When really your not inflating any views this way your just adding views.

**Note**
If you have a linearlayout in your xml when you add another button view to it it will add it below it. If you set the layout orientation to horizontal the button view then gets added beside the other one.

here's a link to an example.
Sorry I would make sure my code matched your code and variables with proper syntax but I am at work.

Comment: @Vahalaru, I already add the buttons in a LinearLayout, the "zones_item" is my button template that add to my LinearLayou

Comment: Ohhh boy, lol if it was a snake it would byte you hang on let me get my computer out and a pen and paper out. You have a mess going on here.

Comment: Also if you could explain exactly what your trying to do. It looks like your trying to have a row of buttons across the top of the screen that you can scroll through as you add them?

Comment: @Vahalaru Mmmm... something like that you  explain, I need to draw a set of Buttons according to my data retrieved from my anko db,  the data that I put in my anko db is from a webservice, I consume the data and save it in a local db, every (called zone button) the plan is for each button display a set of items in my recycler view. Regards